# struts2 jstl iterator tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, iterator, jstl

I have been looking how to implement a thing in struts2 jstl but it is impossible for me to find the way.

When I load the jsp page from the action, I have a list of String lists.

I want to create as divs as elements have the list, but inside every div, I want to create as links as the third element of the sub-list.

So I use the s:iterator tag to parse the list. But I don't know how to iterate "${item[2]}" times inside the first iterator.

The code would be something like this:

```
<s:iterator value="functions" var="item" status="stat">
        <span class="operation">${item[1]}</span>
        <div id="${item[0]}">
            <s:for var $i=0;$i<${item[2]};$i++>
                <a href="#" id="link_$i">Link $i</a>
            </s:for>
        </div>
</s:iterator>
```

Where I have put the s:for tag is where I would like to iterate "${item[2]}" times...

Anyone can help me?

Thank you very much in advance,
Aleix

Comment: What is `functions` and what output you want?

Comment: **functions** is a list where in every position there is a sub-list of Strings. 
I have simplify the code, but what I want more or less is so many divs as sub-lists there are, and in every div so many links as the number in the 3rd position of the sub-list says. 
Thank you;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've got the JSTL core library in scope in your JSP page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

And simply use `<c:forEach>`. Something like this:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${item[2] - 1}">
    <a href="#" id="link_${i}">Link ${i}</a>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thank you Asaph, 
I was trying to do it without mixing the Struts tags (s:) with JSTL tags (c:), but I see that this will be the only way to do it. 
Thank you very much for your answer;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use **`List of Map`** if appropriate, example :

**Action class**

```
// List of raw type Map
private List<Map> functions = Lists.newArrayList(); // with getter

@Override
public String execute() {
    // loops {
        Map map = Maps.newHashMap();
        map.put("id", id);
        map.put("operation", operation);
        map.put("count", count); // count is int/Integer
        functions.add(map);
    // }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

**.jsp**

```
<s:iterator value="functions">
    <span class="operation">${operation}</span>
    <div id="${id}">
        <s:iterator begin="0" end="count - 1" var="link">
            <a href="#" id="link_${link}">Link ${link}</a>
        </s:iterator>
    </div>
</s:iterator>
```

---

**or with `<s:a />` (example)**

```
<s:a action="action_name" id="%{link}" anchor="%{link}">Link ${link}</s:a>
```

**output**

```
<a id="[id]" href="/namespace/action#[anchor]">Link [link]</a>
```

**See also**

> **[Struts2 Guides](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/guides.html)** -> **[Tag Reference](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/tag-reference.html)** -> **[s:iterator](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/iterator.html)**