# An error took place when i use <s:iterator> in javascript

Tags: jsp, struts2

I use `<s:iterator>` in myeclipse and get an error.

But it may not be a syntax error cause my friends can successfully run the program on her computer.Here is my code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd 

">
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:iterator value="{'1','2','3','4','5'}" id='number'> 
    <s:property value='number'/>A 
</s:iterator> 
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: please update your post with that error stack trace.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351767/struts2-jstl-iterator-tag

Comment: you should include the version of frameworks you use. The syntax of the code changed from one version to another and you should check the version against code changes.

Comment: IDE *error*? Just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your iterator to

```
 <s:iterator value='{"1","2","3","4","5"}' id='number'> 
       <s:property value='number'/>A 
 </s:iterator>
```

or you can use

```
<s:iterator value="{1,2,3,4,5}" id='number'> 
       <s:property/>A 
 </s:iterator>
```

or use this

```
<s:iterator value="{'1','2','3','4','5'}" id='number'> 
    <s:property/>A 
</s:iterator>
```